# Unable to make new partition in SD card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I used following command to make new partition in my 32 gb Samsung SD card.

`sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

Then pressed letter o to create a new empty DOS partition table. But it came up with following warning.

> ```
> Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)
> ```

When I ignored the warning and tried to complete partition by writing new table to disk by pressing w, it showed following warning and refused to make new tables.

> ```
> WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
> The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
> the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
> Syncing disks.
> ```

How do I solve this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this problem because `/dev/sdb` is `mounted` (type `mount | grep /dev/sdb` to see), and its meta-information is in the System's RAM, and the system has it "locked" to prevent multiple uncontrolled access . If you `umount /dev/sdb` before you `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`, the system will ensure that the "disk"'s meta-information is up-to-date on "disk", then forget the in-memory copy of the meta-information, and let you adjust/trash the SD card to your heart's content.